# Unique constraint on embedded entity?

Tags: java, persistence, unique-constraint

Is it possible to have a unique constraint over an embedded entity in the javax.persistence library without mentioning all columns individually?

What I have:

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "someReference", "id1", "id2" }) })
public class A {
    @Embedded
    private B embedded;
    private String someReference;
}

@Embeddable
public class B {
    private long id1;
    private long id2;
}
```

What I want (more or less):

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = { @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"someReference", "embedded" }) })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**. When we make any entity as Embedded, it is generally understood that one would never save the same Embedded object in relational databases again once it has been inserted. But there may arise use cases wherein we might want only certain combinations of the Embedded object's attributes to be unique for the relational database.

For document data store, it is Ok to have the same embedded object being present in different documents within a schema.